# Ubuntu server nmcli is not showing SSIDs

Tags: networking, wifi, ubuntu, connection, server

I have Raspberry Pi 4 with Ubuntu server 64 bit [installed](https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi). I'm trying to connect my Pi with another Wi-Fi but unable to connect. I used `netplan` to connect with first Wi-Fi successfully connected. but later on, tried to connect with different SSID using `nmcli` but device is not listing SSIDs and or list.

I have tried below steps

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interface.
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp

sudo iwlist wlan0 scan
```

its list all the wifi properly

```
sudo nmcli device wifi list
```

IN-USE  SSID  MODE  CHAN  RATE  SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY

test 2 :

$ `rfkill list`
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no

2. `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart && dhclient`

[ ok ] Restarting networking (via systemctl): networking.service.
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted

```
4.    nmcli radio
```

WIFI-HW  WIFI     WWAN-HW  WWAN
enabled  enabled  enabled  enabled

```
nmcli radio wifi on

sudo nmcli device wifi list
```

IN-USE  SSID  MODE  CHAN  RATE  SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY

I tried `nmtui` its also not showing Wi-Fi list

are there any methods I can try to connect with my other Wi-Fi?

Comment: Ubuntu server uses **NEITHER** `/etc/network/interfaces` **NOR** `nmcli` but AFAIK uses `systemd-networkd` (unless you have installed a desktop which uses NetworkManager) so your Question is unanswerable. You will be lucky to find someone on this site who uses it.

Comment: ubuntu server 18.04 comes with netplan right? so I have to use only netplan `50-cloud-init.yaml` to add another wifi, should I replace with existing wifi details to the new one?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of nmcli use netplan.

open yaml file and add wifi details in(spaces are important) -
/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml

```
network:
version: 2
ethernets:
    eth0:
        optional: true
        dhcp4: true
# add wifi setup information here ...
wifis:
    wlan0:
        optional: true
        access-points:
            "ssid":
                password: "123pass00"
        dhcp4: true
        dhcp6: true
```

save and  use command -   sudo netplan try